# Improve code in terms of better approach and flaws

Tags: database, plsql, oracle8i

I have the following PL/SQL code which I am using for calling an API (provided by client)
in order to adjust accounts.

I would like to improve my code if there any short comings or better way or approach in writing this block.

P.S. Unfortunately our client is still using Oracle 8i for their product.

PLSQL Code

```
DECLARE
    v_account_id account_adjustments.account_id%TYPE;
    v_adj_no     account_adjustments.adj_no%TYPE;
    v_old_qty    product_warehouse.new_qty%TYPE;
    v_new_qty    product_warehouse.new_qty%TYPE;
BEGIN
    v_old_qty := NULL;
    v_new_qty := NULL;

    FOR acnt IN (SELECT *
                 FROM   temp_table a) LOOP
        SELECT a.new_qty
        INTO   v_old_qty
        FROM   product_warehouse a
        WHERE  ( a.product_no = acnt.product_no );

        Adjust_accounts (in_service_product_no => acnt.product_no,
                         in_service_qty => acnt.qty,
                         out_account_id => v_account_id,
                         out_adj_no => v_adj_no);

        SELECT b.new_qty
        INTO   v_new_qty
        FROM   product_warehouse b
        WHERE  ( b.product_no = acnt.product_no );

        INSERT INTO account_year_todate
                    (product_no,
                     account_id,
                     adj_no,
                     qty_bad,
                     qty_warehouse,
                     qty_factory)
        VALUES      ( acnt.product_no,
                     v_account_id,
                     v_adj_no,
                     acnt.qty,
                     v_old_qty,
                     v_new_qty );
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      dbms_output.Put_line ('exceptions '
                            || SQLERRM);

      ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Comment: If anyone is voting to close this post, kindly mention the reason for closing. Regards

Comment: it's probably better suited for [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to change:

- Replace `SELECT *` in the For loop cursor with the columns that you actually need.
- Your exception block is what I call a silent killer. That's a debugging nightmare because it does nothing except for suppress exceptions because you aren't logging it, you're not re-raising it - instead just redirecting all exceptions via `put_line` into a buffer, which isn't visible at all, unless you're running the program from a IDE which shows buffer output always, or via SQL*Plus. Change it to a proper logging system.
- I have no idea what `Adjust_accounts` does - and you could probably reduce those 2 select statements and have the amounts returned using the stored procedure you're calling?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions. I am running this anonymous block from IDE so I could see the `put_line` outputs. If I would like to log the exceptions, I would want to capture `acnt.product_no` in exception part, as my loop end before the exception. In this case what is the best approach?  The reason why I have 2 select statements is in `Adjust_accounts` API, it adjusts the accounts and quantities. So first sql is to get old quantity and second sql is to get the new quantity. Regards

Comment: @Polappan it's fine for now, but the moment you move it to QA/staging/production server, you might no longer have the liberty to run the procedure as an anon block from an IDE.  Your best approach would be to have a stored proc running an autonomous transaction and log exceptions into whatever table; with the date, time, userid, [`dbms_output.format_error_backtrace`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_util.htm#i1003874) results and whatever data that you want to store.

Comment: @Polappan as for _as my loop end before the exception_ - the moment there's an exception, the program immediately breaks out from the loop and jumps into the exception section. If you want to store the `acnt.product_no` value, assign it to a local variable like how you're doing for `v_new_qty`, `v_old_qty` and others